# Excel VBA For Each Loop giving out of range error

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have 2 workbooks open, and I am trying to copy one range of cells from one workbook into the other workbook based on a condition. The program keeps on breaking at the first `For Each` loop with the

> Subscript out of range

error and I am lost as to why.

I looked at other threads here, and they said that the error comes from not having an Open workbook. I implemented that, and it still gives me this error.

I am new to VBA. Any ideas?

```
Sub TransferCells()
    Dim aggrange As Range
    Dim AnalyticalCell As Range
    Dim BatchCell As Range
    Dim analyticalwb, batchwb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim SEHPLC, CultureDay As Worksheet

    Set analyticalwb = Workbooks.Open("\\ntucsmafps06.na.jn.com\Hom$\APachall\Ta Big Data\Cas tical Results (4).xlsm")
    Set batchwb = Workbooks.Open("\\nctusmafp0s6.na.jn.com\Hom$\APachall\Ta Big Data\20180420_Fed Batch All Data_0.xlsx")

    For Each AnalyticalCell In analyticalwb.Worksheets("SE-HPLC").Range("A1:A87")
        For Each BatchCell In batchwb.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A125271")
            If AnalyticalCell.Value = BatchCell.Value Then
                Set aggrange = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13))
                aggrange.Copy (Destination = Application.Workbooks("20180420_Fed Batch All Data_0.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)))
            End If
        Next BatchCell
    Next AnalyticalCell
End Sub
```

Comment: When declaring typed variables, each variable must have the `As type` information. in `Dim analyticalwb, batchwb As Excel.Workbook`, only batchwb  is a workbook, analyticalwb is of the default type (variant). Same for `Dim SEHPLC, CultureDay As Worksheet`

Comment: Ok thank you! I fixed that, but it is still giving me the Subscript out of range error at the "For Each AnalyticalCell" line.

Comment: What is ActiveCell? It is a good idea to specify whose sheet Range your are talking about.

Comment: Did I not do that? I thought I said "For Each AnalyticalCell in analyticalwb.Worksheets.Range". Does that not specify the sheet and the range over which I am iterating?

Comment: AnalyticalCell is defined by your loop, but ActiveCell won't change except if you select it. see [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-activecell-property-excel)

Comment: And Range() without an object qualifier points to the activesheet.

Comment: Ok, where should I use this ActiveCell property? Should I get rid of my loop variables and use this ActiveCell instead? I thought about using ActiveCell, but I am trying to compare two cells in two different workbooks to each other, so how would the program compare two Active Cells in two workbooks?

Comment: Don't use ActiveCell at all, use AnalyticalCell and BatchCell.

Comment: Ok, so I changed all the references to ActiveCell in my code to either AnalyticalCell or BatchCell. The program is still unable to move from the initial For Each Loop. Am I misreading something here?

Comment: If you add the line `Set SEHPLC = analyticalwb.Worksheets("SE-HPLC")` after `Set batchwb...`, does the error move to the new line?

Comment: No, it now says that the subscript out of range error is now in the Set SEHPLC line.

Comment: Do you have a trailing space on the end of the worksheet name maybe, like "SE-HPLC "?

Comment: No, it doesn't look like I do. I feel like it has something to do with the way I access my workbooks, but I already opened them. It seems like Excel doesn't know where they are, even though I included the correct path.

Comment: If there's no error on the `Set analyticalwb` line, then the sheet name "SE-HPLC" must be causing the error. You don't by chance have `On Error Resume Next` in your code, do you? Navigate to the "SE-HPLC" tab, then in the Immediate window, put `? ActiveSheet.Name` and `? Len(ActiveSheet.Name)`. Are the results "SE-HPLC" and 7?

Comment: @BigBen, the results are SE-HPLC and 7.

Comment: Hmm - to test your hypothesis that the workbook is causing the issue, does `analyticalwb.Activate` throw an error? If not, does `analyticalwb.Worksheets("SE-HPLC").Activate` throw an error?

Comment: I have figured this part out, thanks guys! It turns out that I had to close the workbooks before I ran the macro. If the workbooks are already open, it can't "open" them up again so it gives an out-of-range error.

Answer (score 2):

Change the problematic code to the following. There are 2 errors there:

```
With Worksheets(ActiveCell.Parent.Name)
    aggrange.Copy Destination:=Application.Workbooks("20180420_Fed Batch All Data_0.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(.Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)), .Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)))
End With
```

1. Destination is a named parameter, thus it should be passed with `:=` and not with `=`;

---

2. To pass a range, based on two cells, you need to pass:

`Range(.Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)), .Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)))` and not `Range()`. `Range()` takes string as arguments.

---

3. Further ideas - the `Dim` should be done per variable. In other languages (C++, etc) it is ok, in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) it is a bit problematic:

---

```
Dim analyticalwb As Excel.Workbook, batchwb As Excel.Workbook
Dim SEHPLC As Worksheet, CultureDay As Worksheet
```

---

4. [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

---

5. Write [Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement) on the top of the Module and see whether it compiles.

Comment: Hmm - I'm not sure on number 2. `Cells(Range1, Range2)` wouldn't work, since it has _RowIndex_ and _ColumnIndex_ arguments. . `Range(Range1, Range2)` would, right?

Comment: @BigBen - true. Did not test it, because of the names of the worksheet, will check it again.

Comment: I changed my code to your suggestion, but the program is still stopping at the initial for loop entrance, so I am unable to see if the suggestion worked.

Comment: @A.P - Can you write `Option Explicit` on the top of the module and see whether it compiles? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement

Comment: It does not compile.

Comment: @A.P - that's really good! It means that if you make sure it compiles, you would probably resolve the error. The VBEditor would help you.

Comment: Hmm ok...I still do not understand the error though. I have defined Analytical Cell as a Range, and I am telling the program to loop through the specified range in the workbook. Why is it telling me that there is a subscript out of range when everything is defined?

Comment: @A.P - Idk. As a first step, try to delete all the code in the loop, and leave only the `For ... Each and Next` and see whether you can compile. E.g. this -> https://gist.github.com/Vitosh/5697ec1682ebafe936ef178453c16302

Comment: Ok, I will try. Also, does it look like I am accessing my workbooks properly, i.e syntax, variables? Or am I missing an Activate command? It looks like Excel cannot find my workbook, even though I explicitly told it the path.

Comment: "It looks like Excel cannot find my workbook" - how, if there's no error on the `Set analyticalwb` line?

Comment: @BigBen - `analyticalwb` is a `Variant` in the OP's code. But there should be an error, yup.

Comment: Agreed - but `Workbooks.Open` returns an object that represents the opened `Workbook`.

Comment: I also had another question about point #2 made above: that part of the code does not work, even after I have changed it to Vityata's suggestion using Range(.Cells(...))). The complier gives me the "Invalid or Unqualified reference" error...Any other ideas?